# When is an HNN extension a free group?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $A$ be a free group and $G = A*_t$. When is $G$ also a free group? 
Suppose $t y t^{-1} = z$ and there is a splitting $A = B*C$ so that $y \in B$ and $z \in C$ and $z$ is a member of some basis of $C$ then clearly $G$ is free. Is this the only case that  $G$ is free?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  This is a theorem of [Shenitzer](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=RT&pg6=RT&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=shenitzer&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=13&mx-pid=69174).  For a modern treatment see, for instance, this [recent paper of Louder](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612222).  I give a proof of a similar fact in section 2 of [this preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2866).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help!
I looked at Louder's paper and I don't quite understand the proof. Since the proof is given for  the amalgamation - I'll revert to that case. One can construct immersions $\Gamma_n \rightarrow R_{n+m-1}$ and $\Gamma_m \rightarrow R_{n+m-1}$ and $t$ immerses in each graph. The composition of immersions is still an immersion so the loops representing $t$ under each map are immersions which are homotopic (since $F_{n+m-1} \cong F_n *_{t} F_m$). Thus the images are different parametrization of the same immersed loop. ---I'm running out of space -- to be continued 

Comment: Now looking at the space $X$ constructed by an annulus mapping into $\Gamma_n \cup \Gamma_m$ via the immersions of $t$, one can extend the immersion of the graphs to an immersion of $X$. Great. Now he says that if we look at preimages of midpoints of $R_{n+m-1}$ then we get a forest. But I don't see how it isn't just a collection of arcs. The boundary of the annulus is mapped to the same loop (possibly under different parametrization) so it is just a collection of arcs. Also, why this implies that one of the boundaries crosses some edge only once is unclear to me... many thanks for your time!

Comment: ok. I feel stupid. Of course the edges get identified at the endpoints. Thanks for the references!!

Comment: spring: there is a newer, easier to read version of 'recent paper...'. I'll send you a copy if you're interested.